# Debug mode banner is not removed

Tags: flutter

I am working on a Flutter app and want to hide the debug mode banner.

This is my code for main.dart:

```
Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  FlutterError.onError = FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError;
   //FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.crash();

  runApp(new MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: new MyApp(), 
  ));
}
```

The debug mode banner is not removed, it is shown as always.

What do I need to change to get it removed?

Comment: maybe it is because `MyApp()` has its own `MaterialApp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug banner does not remove from main method, you just follow the example and you bind your MyApp() with the MaterialApp()

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: NextPage(),
    );
  }
}
```